# Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'show'

Tags: jquery

In the console:

```
$('#rhscol') //gives the result below: 

<div id=​"rhscol" style=​"border:​  1px solid red;​">​
    Hello world!
</div>​
```

But in the same console:

```
$('#rhscol').show(); //Gives the result below: 
TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'show'
```

Could someone please explain to me what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: try `jQuery('#rhscol').show();` in the console also `jQuery === $` if you have jQuery included in the page... also make sure the code is included after jQuery is included

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the chrome console's shortcut for `document.querySelector`.

Here is the code from the dev tools source code:

```
 $: function (selector, start)
    {
        if (this._canQuerySelectorOnNode(start))
            return start.querySelector(selector);

        return inspectedWindow.document.querySelector(selector); // <- here
    },
```

Your code above is using jQuery. You need to include jQuery in the page if you want to use it.

Comment: I doubt `$('#rhscol')` would work without jQuery in the page. Of course I have included jQuery in the page

Comment: @Lomse It does, go to your console in a page without jQuery and try it :) It's an alias for querySelector and returns a `Node`. You can hide it with `$("#rhscol").style.display = "none"` . What does `jQuery("#rhscol")` produce? You might be running in no conflict mode, or in a closure, or just in some setting intentionally not exposing the $ sign.